# Laravel: static::create vs DB:insert

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

If I use the following code snippet in my model it inserts the data:

```
$instance = DB::table('users')->insert(compact('email', 'username'));
```

But if I do this instead:

```
$instance = static::create(compact('email', 'username'));
```

It inserts null, but created_at and updated_at are inserted.

Comment: can you show us the complete method (where is $email, $username)

Comment: Sure, public static function store($email, $username){ $instance = static::create(compact('email', 'username')); }

Comment: The same method for both DB and Eloquent way.

Comment: if you want to add multiple rows with single `Medel::xxx` command then you must have to use `::insert($data)`

Answer (score 4):

Laravel's `created_at`/`updated_at` are part of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`. A raw `DB::table` query builder isn't an Eloquent model and thus doesn't have those automatic parameters.

`NULL` data is being inserted in the Eloquent query because Eloquent has a `$fillable` parameter you need to define. This parameter sets which columns can be mass-assigned. Laravel strips attributes not in this array when you do a `fill`, `create`, or otherwise instantiate a new object. In your model, you'd want:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
  protected $fillable = ['email', 'username'];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include that in the above snippets. But I have a        protected $fillable = ['email', 'username'];

Comment: Does it work if you do `User::create(['email' => $email, 'username' => $username])` instead of the `compact` call?

Comment: You are not getting any errors in `apache2/error.log` and you have enabled debug mode on laravel

Comment: None, the only "error" I get from laravel: `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'users_email_unique' (SQL: insert into ``users` (`updated_at`, `created_at``) values (2015-01-06 21:52:35, 2015-01-06 21:52:35))`

Comment: @Prezioso You'd get that if `$email` is blank or if the attribute is being filtered out by the fillable functionality. Do `dd($email)` and see if it matches what you think it's supposed to be.

Comment: If I do dd($email); I get the assigned email from my form.

Comment: Do you have anything in `protected $guarded`?

Comment: Well, I didn't solved this, as wny it worked one way, and not the other. But I created a repo instead and did not use the method inside the user model. And I think this is why it did not work. However, I have seen this work other places.

Answer (score 0):

ceejayoz answer is great, here's an explanation of how to call the model. Once the model is created, let's say this model:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
  protected $fillable = ['email', 'username'];
}
```

Then you need to call by using the model directly and eloquents ORM like so:

```
// example is this. True method is TableName->ColumnName = Value;
$user = User::find($id);
$user->username = '';
$user->fullname = '';
$user->save();
```

The save will update the columns based on what you describe. With this you don't even need the fillable variable.

Some other variables for models that are good to know is:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'userid';   #if you have an primarykey that isn't named id
protected $table = 'tablename';     #if table name isn't pulling by the name of the model
protected $timestamps = true;       #bool value, whether u have timestamp columns in table
```

Answer (score -3):

You said us that you done

```
class User extends Eloquent {
  protected $fillable = ['email', 'username'];
}
```

however in your comment you told us you got the following error in your apache log

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' 
for key 'users_email_unique' (SQL: insert into ``users 
(updated_at, created_at``) values (2015-01-06 21:52:35, 2015-01-06 21:52:35))
```

Make sure to also include `users_email_unique`in your fillable array if you want to set it.

```
class User extends Eloquent {
  protected $fillable = ['email', 'username', 'users_email_unique'];
}
```

Comment: `users_email_uniquein` is the name of the MySQL `UNIQUE` key. It is not a column name.